# How to detect if Extension Manager for has already been installed?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mac

I have Illustrator CS6 and want to install some common plugin. This plugin needs Extension Manager installed.

How can I detect if Extension Manager exists on my Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the Applications folder (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

[image]

If one were to try and install an extension, without Extension Manager installed, there would be a warning stating the Mac didn't know what application to use to open the file.

Comment: You should install more versions of the Creative Suite ;)

Comment: Can't :) They no longer run on the system.:)

Comment: I'll send you my two old Macs: OSX 10.4 and OS 9.?. Then you can answer ANY question!

Comment: errr.. I've got old Macs, just not 3 hours to watch them do anything anymore :)

Comment: @Scott Next time I'll ask you directly - as you can see the question has downvoted karma (probably someone was born with Ai knowledge in the genes)

Comment: @Ilan The question shows a lack of research. It seems like a very obvious solution.

Comment: Try to search it itself ;) probably obvious but not streight forward... for a new mac user

Comment: These kinds of questions never score very well here. I zeroed you out to return balance to the force ;)